# How to use node-jose with jwt token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-jose

I using `jsonwebtoken` to get the token using `sign` method.

I want to encrypt the payload inside the token. so I do it by using [node-jose](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose).

`createEncrypt` give me a token. so now I need to call sign method and pass the `token` (from createEncrypt) to the payload like this?

```
var token = await JWE.createEncrypt(options, key)
    .update(payload, "utf8")
    .final();

const tokenJwt = jsonwebtoken.sign({ token }, 'secret', ..);
```

or this is my token now (from createEncrypt), and I just need to verify using `node-jose` without using jsonwebtoken?

Accoring to jwt.io, the token from `createEncrypt` is not valid (Invalid Signature)

[image]